# Google Form email notification

Tags: google-forms

I'm looking to have the information submitted on a google form to be on the email notification that I receive.  I have tried several things but I can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: " I have tried several things" - Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new form in Google Docs, if you haven’t done that yet, add the necessary fields to the form and save your changes. Now go back to Google Docs and open the spreadsheet corresponding to that particular form.

Choose **Tools > Notification rules...** and select the option that says **Notify me when... A user submits a form**. You can also set how frequently you would like to be notified – right away or with daily digest.

Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588

Comment: Is there a way to add a custom email to notification rule? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the notification in your email, you can refer to the this Google [add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-notifications/bbpdeojefjfhaelgljjcadpcckdfcdod).

Also to enable the data or responses to appear in notification you have to enter a script in the form. which basically tries to extract the columns from the spreadsheet. Sample:
`var p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var column = p.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];`

I hope you build the script by yourself!